# Changing a button's Alpha to 0 while still being able to click it on xCode/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, alpha

When I change a button's Alpha to 0 I can no longer click it, is there another attribute I need to change so the button becomes hidden while still being clickable?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YszF3.png)

Comment: Do you want to be able to make that button visible at some later time by resetting that property, or do you just want an invisible button?

Comment: Invisible buttons are not clickable. There is probably a better solution that invisible button. What are you trying to do? Hint - `UIControl` is almost always a better alternative than `UIButton` in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color to clear color

```
btn.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 0):

The system treats a button as disabled when it's alpha is 0. That's usually what you want.

As Ibrahim suggested, you should be able to set the text color and/or background color to clear to make your button invisible but still clickable.